# Access certificate from silverlight server-side.

Tags: c#, silverlight, iis, certificate

I'm trying to access certificate that placed in Current_user my certificate store.

And when I'm debbugging, for instance, MVC 4 app it is OK, but then i'm trying to access certificate from silverlight's server-side... and can't see any certificates in my x509store.

So as I understand I need to grant IIS-account access to this store.

Is it true? And how can I do it?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "Silverlight server-side"? Silverlight's code is executed on the client, not server.

Comment: actually it's misanderstanding :) Not Silverlight server-side code but server-side code

Comment: Ok, so does it go wrong when you deploy on IIS?

Comment: When i'm debuggin' on IIS

Answer (score 1):

To give IIS access means to give permission to the user that is running the application pool of your IIS website. You should do the following steps:

1. Open `mmc.exe` (Microsoft Management Console).
2. Go to File -> Add/Remove Snap In...
3. Select Certificates.
4. Select the store (in your case it will be `My user account`)
5. Find the certificate (should be in `Personal` folder but it depends on how it was installed).
6. Right-click on the certificate, select Tasks -> Manage Private Keys
7. Add your IIS application pool user and give required access (this is actually a permission to the file where the certificate is stored).